# Decode button URL path

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom, dom-events

How to decode button URL path like this:

```html
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M9.06941 15.0868C9.02328 15.0291 8.9709 14.9767 8.91324 14.9306L2.21148 9.56918C1.90334 9.32267 1.98882 8.83309 2.36225 8.70557L21.0361 2.32913C21.4292 2.1949 21.8051 2.57077 21.6709 2.96388L15.2944 21.6377C15.1669 22.0112 14.6773 22.0967 14.4308 21.7885L9.06941 15.0868ZM10.5386 14.5221L14.4638 19.4285L19.5931 4.40691L4.57147 9.53624L9.47793 13.4614L12.4697 10.4697C12.7626 10.1768 13.2374 10.1768 13.5303 10.4697C13.8232 10.7626 13.8232 11.2374 13.5303 11.5303L10.5386 14.5221Z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Please, clarify what do you mean? How do you want to use the decoded value?
Maybe you mean "How to encode svg to base64 img url"?

Comment: I need URL action path. I'm assuming this is an URL action path.

Comment: Maybe you can give an example code that will use "URL"?

Comment: Sample is [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/H19Y94Fi). I want find reconstruct url of message box "Send" button action (with parameters).

Comment: @Kirill Sample is [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/H19Y94Fi). I want to find and reconstruct url of message box "Send" button action (with parameters). I tried analyze code in Mozilla Inspector panel in the Web Developer Tools, but did not find where exactly it locate

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what your question is. Can you write a short code example where the "decoded" result will be used?

Comment: Sorry that I was unclear. What I want is construct a correct POST request code (with all parameters) to send data to a server, that can be executed from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what the `<path>` element does.

Path describes a series of points in the vector image. The path draws a line between those points, forming an image.

In other words, it is not an encoded URL to a location of an image.

Here's a link to the explanation by Adobe:
https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/file-types/image/vector/svg-file.html

UPDATE:

Sending a POST request from the command line, including some payload (parameters as you call it) can be done in many ways.

To mimic a form you would do the following:

```
curl -X POST https://your/backend/location
   -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
   -d "key1=value1&key2=value2"
```

To send the parameters as a JSON object, do the following:

```
curl -X POST https://your/backend/location
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -d '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: You are right, what I wanted to find is how to construct a proper POST request command that can be executed from the command line.

Comment: That does not seem to have anything to do with your question. Can you explain further?

Comment: well, I mixed up the 'send' button svg URL path with the POST request code. What I need is construct a POST request code (with all parameters) when click on that 'send' button, to send data to the server.

Comment: The POST request is automatically created when using the following code

`<form method="POST" action="your_url">
  <input type="submit" value="send the form">
</form>`

If you want to send a POST request without using a form, you need some Javascript.

Comment: I want to send it from command line as cURL.

Comment: I've updated my answer, have a look